# I am trying to convert this vbscript into code I can use in visual studio

Tags: vbscript, vb6

I'm trying to make an auto-form filler. I have a vbscript I am using that works, but I am having trouble converting it so I can use it in Visual Studio with a Visual Studio web browser instead of IE. The main problem I am having is I can't access the items on a page (ie VALUE,VALUE1,etc.) Any suggestions?

VBscript (works) code:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
intHighNumber = 193949
intLowNumber = 1

For i = 1 to 5
  Randomize
  intNumber = Int((intHighNumber - intLowNumber + 1) * Rnd + intLowNumber)
Next
s = cstr(intNumber)
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
IE.Navigate "INSERTURL"
IE.Visible = True
Wscript.Sleep 1000
IE.Document.All.Item("AVALUE").Value = "6"
IE.Document.All.Item("AVALUE1").Value = "2"
IE.Document.All.Item("AVALUE2").Value = "2000"
IE.Document.All.Item("AVALUE3").Value = s
IE.Document.All.Item("pass").Value = "nono2355"
IE.Document.All.Item("MaleBtn").Click
IE.Document.All.Item("passConfirm").Value = "nono2355"
IE.Navigate "AURL2&resize,128px"
WshShell.AppActivate "IE"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

VB (Failed) code:

```
Dim intHighNumber = 193949 
Dim intLowNumber = 1 
Dim intNumber As Integer

For i = 1 To 5
  Randomize()
  intNumber = Int((intHighNumber - intLowNumber + 1) * Rnd() + intLowNumber)
Next

WebBrowser1.Navigate("ANURL")
WebBrowser1.Visible = True
WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item("VALUE1").Value = "6"
WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item("VALUE2").Value = "2"
WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item("VALUE3").Value = "2000"
WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item("VALUE4").Value = intNumber.ToString
WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item("pass").Value = "nono2355"
WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item("MaleBtn").Click()
WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item("passConfirm").Value = "nono2355"
WebBrowser1.Navigate("ANURL2")
End Sub
```

Comment: Please take the time to properly format your code. Also, Visual Studio is an IDE, not a language. You don't "convert code from VBScript to Visual Studio". Do you mean "convert from VBScript to VB.Net", or "convert from VB6 to VB.Net"? (VBScript <> VB6, so it's either one or the other; it can't be both.)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a DoEvents Loop after the Navigate command to allow the document to be loaded before the code to set values runs.

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("ANURL")
WebBrowser1.Visible = True
While WebBrowser1.Busy Or WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend
WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item("VALUE1").Value = "6"
...
```